# Percentage of total changes on applying filter

Tags: tableau-api

I have a data table with three dimensions and one measure. For each row, I am trying to calculate the percentage of total (calculated by taking the sum of rows) using a calculated field.

As seen in the screenshot attached, For the column titles 'Dec-19' I want the values to be a percentage of current value / grand total (calculated at the bottom as 122,187)
Screenshot of DataTable:
[image: Screenshot of DataTable]

So e.g. for the Column B value of 2000, the Dec-19 column should be (97/122,187) * 100 = 0.079.

I have achieved this by creating a calculated field with the formula: SUM (sales) / MAX ({EXCLUDE (Column B): Sum (sales}), where sales is the measure used in the datatable.

However, upon application of filter on column B, the percentage value changes. e.g. if I select the value 2000 in my filter for column B, I get the percentage as 100%. It seems as if the percentage is being calculated based on only the rows in the filter.

Comment: Hi Welcome to SO.  So do you want these calculations unaffected by filter? Right?

Comment: Moreover please tell whats the third column title actually.  Dec-19 seems one if its value only

Comment: Please use a screen capture utility of some kind; don't just take a photograph of your monitor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you haven't included any sample data, I created some sample data like this, hope this resemble yours.

[image]

Thereafter, I built a cross-tab view in tableau, somewhat like yours

[image]

If that is the scenario, use a calculated field, say `CF` like this, instead of yours

```
([Sales])/
{FIXED [Col1], DATETRUNC('month', [Col3]) : sum([Sales])}
```

Dragging it in the view

[image]

and thus, filtering won't affect your calculation

[image]

Comment: Thank you Anil for your response. I tried the method suggested by you, I am getting the percentages, but the value is incorrect (looks like it is not calculating using table down). I am using the formula for calculated field: (Sales)/{Fixed [Col1], DateTrunc ('month', [Col3] : Sum(Sales)}. The value I obtained for Col1 - Case 1, col2 - 300 and col3 - Dec 19 is 0.7% when it should be 9.0% (10954/122187), and the sum of percentages of all rows is not adding upto 100%.  Do you think I need to update my formula?

Comment: Can you please share a screenshot of the complete view you have built?